# How to add querySelectorAll() function to Element for IE <= 7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, selectors-api

With the code from [this article](http://www.codecouch.com/2012/05/adding-document-queryselectorall-support-to-ie-7/) I've successfully added `querySelectorAll` to `document` in IE7.

But I need to use it on an *element* rather than `document`, like this:

```
var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');   // Works
for (var i=0; i<=containers.length; i++) {
    var container = containers[i];
    container.querySelectorAll('a[data-type="people"]');    // Fails
    // ...
}
```

Is there a way to add `querySelectorAll` to elements in IE7 rather than only to `document`?

Comment: Why not try the [Sizzle library](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation). It's the same selector engine jQuery uses.

Comment: I need to keep the code tiny, no need the unnecessary functions. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Very interesting question.

I would lean toward using a library for this, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), one of the ones mentioned below, [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). Or just using [Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/) (the selector engine jQuery uses in the v1.9 branch).

But answering the question you actually asked:

You can't extend element prototypes on IE7 (sadly), so unless you want to run all of your element instances through a preprocessor function to add `querySelectorAll` to them (the way [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) and [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) work, for instance), you'll have to have a separate function you pass the element into.

Here's one approach to writing that function:

```
var qsaWorker = (function() {
    var idAllocator = 10000;

    function qsaWorker(element, selector) {
        var needsID = element.id === "";
        if (needsID) {
            ++idAllocator;
            element.id = "__qsa" + idAllocator;
        }
        try {
            return document.querySelectorAll("#" + element.id + " " + selector);
        }
        finally {
            if (needsID) {
                element.id = "";
            }
        }
    }

    return qsaWorker;
})();
```

And of course, if you want to use `qsaWorker` in browsers that have `querySelectorAll`, you'd want this:

```
function qsaWorker(element, selector) {
    return element.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

So in total, then, you'd probably want:

```
var qsaWorker = (function() {
    var idAllocator = 10000;

    function qsaWorkerShim(element, selector) {
        var needsID = element.id === "";
        if (needsID) {
            ++idAllocator;
            element.id = "__qsa" + idAllocator;
        }
        try {
            return document.querySelectorAll("#" + element.id + " " + selector);
        }
        finally {
            if (needsID) {
                element.id = "";
            }
        }
    }

    function qsaWorkerWrap(element, selector) {
        return element.querySelectorAll(selector);
    }

    // Return the one this browser wants to use
    return document.createElement('div').querySelectorAll ? qsaWorkerWrap : qsaWorkerShim;
})();
```

Your code using it would then look like this:

```
var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
for (var i=0; i<=containers.length; i++) {
    var container = containers[i];
    var links = qsaWorker(container, 'a[data-type="people"]'); // <== Changed
    // ...
}
```

But again, I would tend to lean toward using a library...