# Accessing HTML Elements that have been created by setting innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, innerhtml

I have a Function which makes an ajax call and then return a piece of html that is inserted into a table's `td` element. using `element.innerHTML=ajaxResult;` Now I want to access the elements in the `ajaxResult` that have the `name` attribute as `special`. So I do a `document.getElementsByName('special')` and expect to get 4-5 elements. But I actually get none.

This makes it impossible for me to access those elements and I am stuck. Please help me resolve this. Thanks in Advance!

I think this is related to the `dom` not reloading after I set `innerHTML`. But not sure how to reload it.

I am using IE8 in IE8 compatibility view and IE7 standards :(

**EDIT**

This is my function

```
function handleStateChange()
{
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState==4 && ajaxRequest.status==200) {                 
        var responseStr = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        var splitResult = responseStr.split("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
        var leftHtml= splitResult [0];
        var rightHtml= splitResult [1];
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=leftHtml;    

        if(rightHtml !="") {
            document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML=rightHtml;
       }


       if(splitResult.length >=3 ){
           var appActionflag = splitResult [2];
           document.getElementById("userAction").innerHTML=appActionflag;
       }

       if(splitResult.length >= 4 ){
           var userId = splitResult [3];
           document.getElementById("userId").innerHTML=userId;
       }

       reverseDNASwitch();
        var grpList = document.getElementsByName('parmGrpId');

        alert('javascript is working! Found:'+grpList.length);

        for(var i=0;i<grpList.length;i++){
           alert('Got GroupId: '+ (i));
           var grpTd = grpList[i];
           grpTd.innnerHTML='Hi';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the elements really have that `name` (`name="special"`), and you're making the call *after* assigning to `innerHTML`, you'll see them in that list (provided the browser supports `getElementsByName`). You'll have to show the markup you're putting in the table and the code around where you're doing that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Crap, Google tricked me. Haha the first two results for "MDN getelementsbyname" are `document.getElementsByName` and `element.getElementsByTagName`, and I read them as the same method :)

Comment: @Ian: Ouch, as I would probably have done. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I (shouldn't have) assumed that the method applied to both - I'm so used to that being the case with `getElementsByTagName`, `querySelector`, `querySelectorAll`, `getElementsByClass`, and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option for your specific scenario, where you want to get elements with a specific attribute (and value), you can use a function like this:

```
function getElementsByAttribute(options) {
    /*if (container.querySelectorAll) {
        var selector = '';
        if (options.tagFilter) {
            selector += options.tagFilter;
        }
        selector += '[' + options.attr;
        if (options.val) {
            selector += '="' + options.val.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"';
        }
        selector += ']';
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(options.container.querySelectorAll(selector));
    }*/
    var elements = options.container.getElementsByTagName(options.tagFilter || "*"),
        ret = [],
        i, cur,
        matches = (function () {
            if (options.val) {
                return function (el) {
                    return el.getAttribute(options.attr) === options.val;
                };
            } else {
                return function (el) {
                    return el.hasAttribute(options.attr);
                };
            }
        })();
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        cur = elements[i];
        if (matches(cur)) {
            ret.push(cur);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And you call it like:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var contain = document.getElementById("container"),
        els = getElementsByAttribute({
            container: contain,
            attr: "name",
            val: "special",
            tagFilter: ""
        });

    console.log("els", els);
};
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/cxq6t/1/

(I kept in my original logic for supporting `querySelectorAll`, but proved not to work in old IE with invalid attributes, per the comments)

The object you pass to the function accepts:

- `container`: containing element to look through
- `attr`: the attribute to look for
- `val`: optional value to match against
- `tagFilter`: optional filter for the tagName of matched elements

I tested in IE7/8 to see if the `<div name="special">` would match, and it does. As well as the other `<input />`s.

If you ever wanted to expand the selector to be more complicated things like what `querySelectorAll` supports, you could use a polyfill like T.J.Crowder's. But this seems to get the job done.

Answer (score 4):

<s>If the table cell you're adding to is, itself, in the DOM, that should work. (And so I may have to delete this answer; originally I thought `document.getElementsByName` had been deprecated, but I was mistaken). Here's an example using `getElementsByName`:</s>

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ofeluf/3) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ofeluf/3/edit)

```
(function() {
  // Get the target
  var target = document.getElementById("target");

  // Dynamically add content
  target.innerHTML =
    '<div name="special">special 1</div>' +
    '<div name="special">special 2</div>' +
    '<div name="special">special 3</div>';

  // Get those elements
  var list = document.getElementsByName("special");

  // Prove we got them
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = "Found " + list.length + " 'special' elements";
  document.body.appendChild(p);
})();
```

Of course, because it's a function of `document`, that will find **all** of the elements with `name="special"`, not just the ones you added to the table cell.

The above does not work on IE if the elements aren't allowed to have the `name` attribute. So for instance, if you look for `getElementsByName("special")`. it will ignore `<div name="special">` but find `<input name="special">`, because `name` is not a valid attribute for `div` elements. Details in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536438%28VS.85%29.aspx). Worse, IE will include elements whose **`id`** matches, even though of course that has nothing to do with `name`. *sigh*

Unless you need to support IE7 and earlier (e.g., unless you're developing for China), you can use `Element#querySelectorAll` with the selector `'[name="special"]'`. That will look only within the element for elements that use that `name` attribute.

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ofeluf/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ofeluf/2/edit)

```
(function() {
  // Get the target
  var target = document.getElementById("target");

  // Dynamically add content
  target.innerHTML =
    '<div name="special">special 1</div>' +
    '<div name="special">special 2</div>' +
    '<div name="special">special 3</div>';

  // Get those elements
  var list = target.querySelectorAll('[name="special"]');

  // Prove we got them
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = "Found " + list.length + " 'special' elements";
  document.body.appendChild(p);
})();
```

If you need to support IE7 or earlier, you might look at [this other Stack Overflow question and my answer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478350/how-to-add-queryselectorall-function-to-element-for-ie-7). The question points to [this article](http://www.codecouch.com/2012/05/adding-document-queryselectorall-support-to-ie-7/) about adding `querySelectorAll` to `document`, and my answer to the question talks about how to emulate that at an element-specific level.

So combining the code from that article with my answer to the other question and the examples above, we get:

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ofeluf/5) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ofeluf/5/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="target"></div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      // IE7 support for querySelectorAll. Supports multiple / grouped selectors and the attribute selector with a "for" attribute. http://www.codecouch.com/
      if (!document.querySelectorAll) {
        (function(d, s) {
            d=document, s=d.createStyleSheet();
            d.querySelectorAll = function(r, c, i, j, a) {
                a=d.all, c=[], r = r.replace(/\[for\b/gi, '[htmlFor').split(',');
                for (i=r.length; i--;) {
                    s.addRule(r[i], 'k:v');
                    for (j=a.length; j--;) a[j].currentStyle.k && c.push(a[j]);
                    s.removeRule(0);
                }
                return c;
            }
        })();
      }

      var qsaWorker = (function() {
          var idAllocator = 10000;

          function qsaWorkerShim(element, selector) {
              var needsID = element.id === "";
              if (needsID) {
                  ++idAllocator;
                  element.id = "__qsa" + idAllocator;
              }
              try {
                  return document.querySelectorAll("#" + element.id + " " + selector);
              }
              finally {
                  if (needsID) {
                      element.id = "";
                  }
              }
          }

          function qsaWorkerWrap(element, selector) {
              return element.querySelectorAll(selector);
          }

          // Return the one this browser wants to use
          return document.createElement('div').querySelectorAll ? qsaWorkerWrap : qsaWorkerShim;
      })();

      // Get the target
      var target = document.getElementById("target");

      // Dynamically add content
      target.innerHTML =
        '<div name="special">special 1</div>' +
        '<div name="special">special 2</div>' +
        '<div name="special">special 3</div>';

      // Get those elements
      var list = qsaWorker(target, '[name="special"]');

      // Prove we got them
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = "Found " + list.length + " 'special' elements";
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which works in IE7.

Comment: can you please post sample code? I am not familiar with this function

Comment: just for being on the safe side, what do I do if I have to support IE7?

Comment: IE7 has about [1.81% global market share](http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0). Do you think it's really likely?

Comment: @MozenRath Use `element.getElementsByTagName("div")`, then loop through them and see which have the `.name` property as "special" - if so, add them to an array, and work with that array. Whatever you end up choosing, make sure it's only used when `element.querySelectorAll` is `undefined`

Comment: Do you have more info on `getElementsByName` being deprecated?  I'm not saying you are wrong, but that is news to me and I couldn't find more info on it after a few searches.  For example, [W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) doesn't mention deprecation and says it is supported in all major browsers.

Comment: @Briguy37: They may well be right. I was basing my statement on the fact it exists (on `Document`) in [DOM1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-71555259) but not in [DOM2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#i-Document) or [DOM3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#i-Document). But I may be wrong, it's in [DOM2HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259). And I wouldn't trust what W3Schools tells you as far as you could throw me (and I'm a beefy guy).

Comment: unfortunately, this code is for corporates that think change is a bitch(well in some cases it really is) so they stick to their 1024x786 CRT mointors and 512 MB RAM. SO no IE8 for them

Comment: @Briguy37: I **am** wrong. Not only is it in the [DOM2HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259) spec as I noted above, but it's in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-document-object) spec as well. Will fix. (I *still* wouldn't trust W3Schools as far as you could throw me, though, and note that it's **not** "W3C Schools". That awful site ([more](http://w3fools.com)) has **nothing whatsoever** to do with the W3C.)

Comment: Thanks for the responses TJ, though I definitely find it strange that it's missing from the DOM2 and DOM3 when it was in DOM1 before.  I'd thought those would document (no pun intended) ALL supported methods (and frankly I'm very impressed that you noticed that it was missing!).

Comment: @Briguy37: No, it actually makes sense, I was just being dumb. DOM1 was very early on and didn't really separate XML and HTML. As of DOM2, they separated the concepts of the "raw" DOM and the DOM stuff related specifically to HTML (such as the `name` attribute), hence the DOM2HTML spec as distinct from the DOM2 spec. What irritates me is I've made this mistake before. :-) Thanks again for calling me on it.

Comment: Guys, I got a problem, This is code is going to work in IE8 compatibility view and IE7 standards :(

Comment: your example does not work if i use it in IE8 compatibility view and IE7 standards

Comment: @MozenRath: Wow, it doesn't even work in IE8. This is because IE ignores elements with `name` where the `name` attribute isn't allowed on the element (so for instance, it won't find `<div name="special">`  but it would find `<input name="special">`). Wow. You'll have to loop through and find them by yourself.

Comment: @MozenRath So are you giving non-input elements a `name` attribute?

Comment: @MozenRath: This is yet another reason not to misuse attributes. :-) But see the updated answer.

Comment: @MozenRath: And finally, I've posted an answer that works with IE7. It's a bit overkill, but there we are...

Comment: sry bro! you helped a lot but am using Ian's function as it is concise.